# Cannot find 'UIDevice' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, apple-watch

I want to get the Device Id of my device and I read about UIDevice but for some reason it's not working in my project, even if I import UIKit. Maybe someone knows why? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: `UIKit` is an iOS framework. It is not available on any other platforms, such as watchOS. You need to use `WatchKit` instead on watchOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIDevice is not available on Apple Watch.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice

Please check this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/25529

There's [`WKInterfaceDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice) for Watches.